# CocoaPod library project creation

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am following [this tutorial here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create) to create my first CocoaPod library (e.g. named `MyLib`), but after I executed the commands, I don't see my library created with the file structures they described on the tutorial.

For example, I don't see `MyLib.xcodeproj` in the root folder `MyLib`, instead I see `_Pods.xcodeproj`; there is no `Pods` directory, although the tutorial says so.

I did this command for linting `pod lib lint MyLib.xcodespec --allow-warnings` and `pod lib lint --allow-warnings`.

The results of both commands is **MyLib passed validation.**

In the `MyLib.xcodespec` file, I have the following dependencies:

```
s.dependency 'SCSiriWaveformView', '~> 1.0.3'
  s.dependency 'SnapKit', '~> 0.22.0'
  s.dependency 'FDWaveformView', '~> 1.0.1'
```

Should I rename `_Pods.xcodeproj` to `MyLib.xcodeproj` so I can write my source code in the directory?

**Edit:**
The structure of my root directory is:

```
_Pods.xcodeproj
Examples 
  |- Pods
  |- Podfile
  |- Podfile.lock
  |- MyLib
  |- MyLib.xcodeproj
  |- MyLib.xcworkspace
  |- Tests

MyLib
  |- Assets
  |- Classes
MyLib.podspec
```

Answer (score 1):

did you do "pod install"?

What is the dir structure that you do have?

Comment: I did `pod install` in my `Example` folder that contains a `Podfile`, but in the root directory, I don't have this file, so I cannot do `pod install` at the root directory. **Please see my edit above for the structure of my root directory. Thanks**

Comment: Hmm. Would you mind posting MyLib.podspec? ps don't rename _Pods.xcodeproj.